# java program to sort a string array in descending order based upon their weight

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to write code for this java program

**Write a java program to sort a string array in descending order based upon their weight.
Weight of string can be calculated in the following way letter A has weight 1 and letter a has weight -1.Likewise letter Z has weight 26 and letter z has -26.
Sample Input:
3
Python Java HTML

Sample Output:
HTML Java Python 
**

i have written following code

```
       import java.util.*; 
       class Sort{
       public static void main(String args[])
       {
         Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
         int n=in.nextInt();
         String[] s=new String[n];
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
           s[i]=in.next();
        }

         int[] arr=new int[n];
         int weight=0;
         String str="";

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
        str=s[i];
          for(int j=0; j<str.length(); j++)
         {
           if((int)str.charAt(j)>64 && (int)str.charAt(j)<91)
           weight+=str.codePointAt(j)-64;
           else
           weight+=96-str.codePointAt(j);
           }
        arr[i]=weight;
        weight=0;
       }
      Arrays.sort(arr);  
    }
   }
```

I calculated weight of each string and stored that in an integer array and sorted that

when input is 
**3
Python Java HTML**

then my int array is returning weight in sorted order

**-66
-14
53**

.....now i am facing problem to link that sorted integer array with the original string to get the output. Help me to complete the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you could use a method to calculate a letter's weight. Something like,

```
private static int getLetterWeight(char ch) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(ch)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (Character.isUpperCase(ch)) ? 1 + (ch - 'A') : -1 - (ch - 'a');
}
```

Then, you can use that to calculate a word's weight. By iterating each letter and summing the weights,

```
private static int weighWord(String str) {
    int weight = 0;
    for (char ch : str.toCharArray()) {
        weight += getLetterWeight(ch);
    }
    return weight;
}
```

Finally, you could create a `Comparator<String>` to compare the weight of the words like

```
private static Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int a = weighWord(o1);
        int b = weighWord(o2);
        if (a < b) {
            return -1;
        } else if (a > b) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
};
```

And then use it to sort your `String`(s)

```
Arrays.sort(arr, comparator);
```

Comment: I find return Integer.compare(a, b); a handy shortcut to the boilerplate if else clause.